# Understanding Azure Function app and Service Bus costs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm playing around with creating a Pub/Sub system using Azure Service Bus Topics and an Azure Function app where the functions are decorated with ServiceBusTrigger. I'm using the standard tier for Service Bus and Consumption Plan for the Function app.

The concept is working fine and will serve my purposes, however, I'm having difficulty understanding how this will affect my Azure costs.

Running just one function with that attribute seems to generate a couple request per second to the Service Bus. In the end, I expect to have quite a few Topics with Subscriptions and an Azure Function for each Subscription.

If I understand correctly, each of the requests that the ServiceBusTrigger generates counts against the number of Service Bus operations you get. With a few functions, I'll go over 13M ops pretty easily.

Some of these subscribers aren't so time sensitive that they'd need to check the Subscription several times per second. Is there a way to change the frequency that ServiceBusTrigger checks the Subscription to reduce costs? Am I approaching this problem from entirely the wrong angle?

Comment: I have some Function apps that watch several SB queues, and I'd been meaning to ask if all that polling was normal behavior, too. Your question reminded me, I posted an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/714) asking about it.

Comment: Thanks @McGuireV10  for the bug report. I have tons like this to report on Azure. Running out of time to find workarounds. Finally we are all doing QA for their profit.

Comment: There is apparently a "message pump" thread doing this polling but as your question notes, it seems inconsistent with the concept of the demand-driven consumption billing plan.

Comment: I'll leave this question, mostly out of curiosity, but in the meantime I've decided to go with Azure Event Grid.

We have very few events in pub/sub right now, but as we grow I think Event Grid will scale better.  You can push to it and it'll fan out calls to subscribers, instead of subscribers polling for events. Seems like a more decoupled system as well. Still interested in hearing about this though!